# Single Sign-On For Google Calendar API?

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, google-calendar-api

I have recently implemented the Google Calendar API into my iOS project using the instructions from this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios#further_reading

After some testing I noticed that I have to sign in each time the user wants to update the calendars from Google, which is not what I want.

I looked around and saw something like GPPSignIn, however that is not incorporated into this specific library.

Does anyone know a way to implement SSO for the calendar specific API that google offers, or do I have to implement it another way using the Google Plus library somehow. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: After the first sign in, subsequent sign in attempts succeed silently with out user login using G+ sign in. You have to call this method trySilentAuthentication. check this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: @SGC The problem though is that the Google Calendar library does not include GPPSignIn or Google Plus files. That library utilizes GTLServiceCalendar and GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch however I don't see anything that incorporates SSO with either one of those.